# Android java.net.UnknowHostException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, uri

I have below code to download image from URL. But getting UnknowHostException:

```
  class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];

        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

I am calling this code like this

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2))
            .execute(ocrResult.getImgUrl());
```

ocrResult.getImgUrl has value as below:

```
http://thumbs1.ebaystatic.com/m/mwXFFYQ1tmdoRBaDVQG2tsA/140.jpg
```

I do have below permision in Android Manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

**Below is entire stack. Its seems to me that URL is getting encoded incorrectly. I see %5c and then "/" after it.**

```
11 17:34:19.109: E/Error(2815): http:%5C/%5C/thumbs4.ebaystatic.com%5C/m%5C/mdfwIytXczq_z11DEJ42J9g%5C/140.jpg
06-11 17:34:19.117: W/System.err(2815): java.net.UnknownHostException: http:%5C/%5C/thumbs4.ebaystatic.com%5C/m%5C/mdfwIytXczq_z11DEJ42J9g%5C/140.jpg
06-11 17:34:19.125: W/System.err(2815):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:279)
06-11 17:34:19.132: W/System.err(2815):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
06-11 17:34:19.132: W/System.err(2815):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
06-11 17:34:19.132: W/System.err(2815):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
06-11 17:34:19.140: W/System.err(2815):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
06-11 17:34:19.140: W/System.err(2815):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
06-11 17:34:19.187: D/dalvikvm(2815): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1370K, 29% free 6738K/9360K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
06-11 17:34:19.195: W/System.err(2815):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
06-11 17:34:19.203: W/System.err(2815):     at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(CaptureActivity.java:854)
06-11 17:34:19.203: W/System.err(2815):     at edu.sfsu.cs.orange.ocr.CaptureActivity$DownloadImageTask.doInBackground(CaptureActivity.java:1)
06-11 17:34:19.210: W/System.err(2815):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:300)
06-11 17:34:19.218: W/System.err(2815):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-11 17:34:19.218: W/System.err(2815):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:240)
06-11 17:34:19.226: W/System.err(2815):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-11 17:34:19.226: W/System.err(2815):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-11 17:34:19.226: W/System.err(2815):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: added entire error stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a wrong URL(`which is character encoded URL`) from your execute parameter but you can still get the correct URL using the replaceAll method of the String by replace all instances of `%5C` with empty character.

**solution:**

```
String urldisplay = urls[0].replaceAll("%5C","");
```

**result:**

```
http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mdfwIytXczq_z11DEJ42J9g/140.jpg
```

Comment: @Amit always check logcat.. :))

Answer (score 1):

`%5c` is a url encoded backslash. Looks like your string's forward slashes are being escaped with backslashes like so:

```
http:\/\/thumbs1.ebaystatic.com\/m\/mwXFFYQ1tmdoRBaDVQG2tsA\/140.jpg
```

and later when you pass in this URL, all the backslashes are converted to `%5c`.

Make sure your string doesn't have its forward slashes escaped before passing it into `DownloadImageTask`. The proper way to do this is

```
url = url.replaceAll("\\", "");
```